# Homebrew on macOS: how to find older versions of a brew formula?

Tags: package, version, homebrew, versioning, changelist

Homebrew used the have the `versions` command to show a list of all previous versions of a specific formula. For example:

`brew versions mysql`

Would show a list of all older versions of the `mysql` formula.

For some reason the `versions` command has been removed. What is the correct way to do this nowasays?

FYI using Homebrew 2.4.2 on macOS 10.15.5 Catalina.

Comment: Why do you need that list for? `brew search mysql` gives you the officially-supported older versions.

Comment: @bfontaine I need the list because on several occasions I found myself in need of installing a particular previous version. Either to compare features or differences, or to workaround some incompatibility. By the way this was not explicitly about mysql, that was just an example here, my question was just in general about any formula.

Comment: @bfontaine Also thanks for mentioning `search`, but that seems to list only a few specific versions, not the entire version history (like the `versions` command used to do). For example if I do `brew search ffmpeg` I get `ffmpeg` (i.e. the latest) and `ffmpeg@2.8` however I know there have been many more versions.

Answer (score 0):

`versions` command has been removed and homebrew-versions repo also got removed.

For the homebrew formula versions, you can find more details in [this doc](https://docs.brew.sh/Versions).

As for `mysql` formula, we have different versions tracked down `mysql@5.6`, `mysql@5.7`, and `mysql` (aka `mysql@8.0`). For each release line, homebrew always keep it to the latest.

Let me know if it helps.